# Can't resolve 'net' and 'child_process' in ..\..\..\chrome-launcher\dist error after importing from 'html-pdf-chrome' library

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to use `html-pdf-chrome` library in my reactjs project. I ran `npm install --save html-pdf-chrome` with no issues. However, when I import a module from this library like the following:

```js
import { create as createPdf} from 'html-pdf-chrome';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\Project\project\node_modules\html-pdf-chrome\node_modules\chrome-launcher\dist'
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js 16:21-45
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/lib/src/index.js
 @ ./src/containers/Performance/PerformanceContainer.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/App.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.dev.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-finder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\Project\project\node_modules\html-pdf-chrome\node_modules\chrome-launcher\dist'
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-finder.js 11:35-59
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/lib/src/index.js
 @ ./src/containers/Performance/PerformanceContainer.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/App.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.dev.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\Project\project\node_modules\html-pdf-chrome\node_modules\chrome-launcher\dist'
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js 17:24-48
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/lib/src/index.js
 @ ./src/containers/Performance/PerformanceContainer.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/App.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.dev.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\Project\project\node_modules\html-pdf-chrome\node_modules\chrome-launcher\dist'
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js 18:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/html-pdf-chrome/lib/src/index.js
 @ ./src/containers/Performance/PerformanceContainer.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/App.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.dev.jsx
 @ ./src/containers/Main/Root.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx
```

This is the package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.8",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.9",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^4.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.36",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.0",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.14",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.1.9",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.1.9",
    "@use-it/event-listener": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chrome-launcher": "^0.13.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.6.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.0",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.4",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "framework7": "^5.6.0",
    "framework7-react": "^5.6.0",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.5",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "html-pdf-chrome": "^0.6.1",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "json2mq": "^0.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-table": "^1.50.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.5.0",
    "notistack": "^0.9.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.7.0",
    "query-string": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dnd": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-preview": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dnd-scrollzone": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.2",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.3.1",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.4",
    "react-router": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.91",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.11.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "react-truncate-html": "^0.1.7",
    "recharts": "^1.6.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.2",
    "redux-promise-middleware-actions": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rsuite": "^4.6.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.20.1",
    "simplebar": "^5.0.7",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.0.10",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.9.0-alpha.20",
    "thunk": "^0.0.1",
    "use-react-router": "^1.0.7",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack --watch --config webpack.project.dev.js",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p --config webpack.project.prod.js",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "0.0.19",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```